# Tomee won't deploy anymore, no logs files produced

Tags: tomcat, deployment, apache-tomee

I have one remote server and one local server where are running the same applications with "tomee webprofiles".
From today, without having made any changes, I can not deploy any applications in the remote server. When I press the "start" button to deploy, the tomcat manager page remains in infinite loading, and this does not produce any output.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try restarting the remote deployer? If it's not running over SSL, can you try doing a chrome inspector or  TCPDump to see what's happening?

Comment: I tried everything, I thought the problem could be the update of the sdk. I "solved" by updating tomee from 1.7.1 to 7.0. Thank you!